# Joomla 3.3.3 - PHP being stripped no matter what method I use

Tags: joomla

Yes, I've Googled, and used all the usual methods before. They aren't working.

There are times I need to use PHP within a Joomla module. The classic example is a dynamic year in a copyright statement.

```
<p><br />Copyright © 
<?php echo date( "Y"); ?> Name Of Site. All rights reserved. </p>
```

But there are plenty of other times I need PHP - so I'm not just looking for an alternative to get dynamic year. I'm looking to execute PHP in a module.

I can't pinpoint when the usual methods stopped working, but they did. I've got several sites in development now where the usual methods simply don't work. Turning off text filters for Super Admin, and/or using Sourcerer, DirectPHP, AnyCode. None of them are working now. The PHP is either output to the browser as plain text, or else something inserts HTML comments around it.

Comment: Are you saying this code is in the layout file of your module or that you have stuck it into the edit field of a custom html module?

Comment: Custom HTML module or AnyCode module (an extension designed to, you guessed it, allow any code). it didn't matter which. The problem turned out to be that "Prepare content" was set to "No" on the modules where it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague found the problem.

"Prepare content" was set to "No" on the modules where it wasn't working. It needs to be set to "Yes". Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what may have stopped working with your site, but I have a Joomla website running 3.3.3, with DirectPHP, and it still works. That said, I would guess that it could be a problem with the server that you are running on, if you didn't make any changes to your Joomla installation. Did you change any php settings on your server recently?

Comment: They are on the same shared server, using the same php.ini as a different Joomla site where it does work. And the Joomla versions match ... so it's not a minor Joomla release change. Hmm.

Comment: Try uploading a plain php file, like test.php with:
`<?php phpinfo();
?>` or something else simple.

Comment: PHP works fine on the server outside of Joomla ... that's how Joomla is  even working, after all.  Yes, a standalone PHP file on the same server loaded in the browser works as expected.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. And I can't believe I forgot to think that Joomla is still running. Maybe you could try uninstalling/reinstalling your plugins (if you haven't already).